# Unable to parse yaml file python

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have a sample YAML file and I'm unable to parse it using PyYAML library.

`setup.yml`:

```
key: HostName
deviceid: port1
```

Python code

```
with open('../configs/setup.yml') as stream:
    try:
        print 'yaml.data ==', yaml.load(stream)
        print 'yaml.data ==', type(yaml.load(stream))
        # print 'yaml.data ==', dict(yaml.load(stream))
        data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
        self.device_id = data['deviceid']
        self.key = yaml.load(stream)['key']
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

The `yaml.load(stream)` type is `Nonetype`, I thought it should be a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you read the stream with the first `load()` there is no more data in the stream and the next load returns `None` and doesn't throw an Error (e.g. end of stream)..

What you could do is:

```
import yaml

with open('../configs/setup.yml') as stream:
    print 'yaml.data ==', yaml.load(stream)
    stream.seek(0, 0)
    print 'yaml.data ==', type(yaml.load(stream))
    # print 'yaml.data ==', dict(yaml.load(stream))
with open('../configs/setup.yml') as stream:
    data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    device_id = data['deviceid']
    key = data['key']
```

or just store the loaded document in data from the start. I removed the reference to `self.` because of the previous errors, you never came to that undefined variable.

However, there is almost never a need to use PyYAML's `load()` (and that is certainly true here) **it is unsafe** and doesn't warn you about that. With uncontrolled data it can wipe your disc, or worse.